# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline giving Dockerfile error

Tags: node.js, docker, express, continuous-integration, gitlab

Good Evening,
I am trying to deploy my nodeJS app to my Digital Ocean Server and its saying it cant find my Dockerfile. I did check and the Dockerfile does not have a .txt extension. Any guidance is appreciated. I have my variables set in my Gitlab project.
The pipeline throws the below error:
"$ chmod og= $ID_RSA
chmod: unrecognized option: ---BEGIN
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
Usage: chmod [-Rcvf] MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
Each MODE is one or more of the letters ugoa, one of the
symbols +-= and one or more of the letters rwxst
-R  Recurse
-c  List changed files
-v  List all files
-f  Hide errors"

```js
stages:
  - build
  - publish
  - deploy

variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

build:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
    - echo   "ACCOUNT_SID=$ACCOUNT_SID" >> .env
    - echo   "AUTH_TOKEN=$AUTH_TOKEN" >> .env
    - echo   "API_KEY=$API_KEY" >> .env
    - echo   "API_SECRET=$API_SECRET" >> .env
    - echo   "PHONE_NUMBER=$PHONE_NUMBER" >> .env
    - echo    "sengrid_api=$sengrid_api" >> .env

publish:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build . -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST 
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    - docker push $TAG_LATEST

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - deployment
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker pull $TAG_COMMIT"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker container rm -f my-app || true"
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "docker run -d -p 80:3000 --name my-app $TAG_COMMIT"
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://167.172.225.124
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check first if the [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) argument order is correct:

Instead of:

```
docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
```

I would try:

```
docker build . -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST
```

Check also you are in the right path when you are running this build command.
And that there is a file named `Dockerfile` (the default name needed by `docker build`).

---

Regarding the error:

```sh
chmod og= $ID_RSA 
chmod: unrecognized option: ---BEGIN
```

You need to apply `chmod` on a file, not on a file *content*.
The variable `ID_RSA` includes the key itself, not the key filename.

Use `~/.ssh/id_rsa` instead of `$ID_RSA`.

Comment: Oh my lanta, i misplaced the . thank you. Now I am getting a new error for the final stage which is to deploy. I will add the error to the top. it sats chmod: unrecognized option: --BEGIN

Comment: I added it and got an error for it saying it cant file the file or directory, but ill make another question for that since that is out of the scope of this question. Thank you for all of your help and the time you took with your answers. I am new to Ci/CD and the explanations help.

Comment: @augdog97 No problem. I will follow your next question.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I posted the new question.

Comment: "You need to apply chmod on a file, not on a file content." You said. But in my case, $ID_RSA is a file. A CI variable with file type.

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER OK. That was not the case for me, but if it is a file, then it will work indeed.

Comment: I have the same problem. I saved ID_RSA as a file and breakline at the end. but i get this error. how did you solve it?

Comment: @aliFalahati Check you key (and parent folder) [permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595537/7490), as [in here](https://gist.github.com/denisgolius/d846af3ad5ce661dbca0335ec35e3d39).

Answer (score 9):

If you have followed [**this tutorial**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-registering-a-gitlab-runner) as I do (which looks to be the case), It looks the tutorial assumes to run on the master branch, protected.

I was running on another branch not protected. So I had to unprotect all variables to work on unprotected branches. The job succeeds immediately.

Comment: Yes, the Protected Branch was the point on my env either. But, It doesn't have any problem with Variables whose type are `variable`.

Comment: Thanks, but I preferred to protect the branch that I was working on.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your ID_RSA variable is
[Type: file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L32Tk.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod og= $ID_RSA
```

For me it didn't work because i copied key without breakline symbol  in the end ,it turned out that is important.
Tried many solutions, spent almost a day before i got this /.