# How to change chmod for Gitlab Variable?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

My deploy stage failed,just that line

```
chmod og= $STAGE_ID_RSA
```

Got error

```
chmod og= $STAGE_ID_RSA
BusyBox v1.34.1 (2022-04-04 10:19:27 UTC) multi-call binary.
Usage: chmod [-Rcvf] MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
MODE is octal number (bit pattern sstrwxrwxrwx) or [ugoa]{+|-|=}[rwxXst]
    -R  Recurse
    -c  List changed files
    -v  Verbose
    -f  Hide errors
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I read this
[Gitlab CI/CD pipeline error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679580/gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-giving-dockerfile-error)
but I do not have .ssh on Gitlab server(located on other server).
How to change file content permission?

Answer (score 3):

check if "STAGE_ID_RSA" is saved as "file" not "variable" on the gitlab's variable configuration page.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was simply setting the variables as protected only, which means they are only visible for protected branches. The selected branch for the pipeline was not set to protected and so the variable for the ID_RSA key (which definitely has to get set as a file) was not available leading to the same result.

I did solve the problem by

- setting the variable to type file
- remove the protected flag from the variable
  or
- set the current branch as protected branch